# Trouble installing xhprof

Tags: lamp, php, pecl

I'm currently trying to install the xhprof (PECL) extension onto my Mediatemple gridserver. I'm having a bit of a time of it since write restrictions won't allow the PECL installer to work. I've done the following:

```
mkdir /home/#####/data/lib/xhprof-0.9.2
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/xhprof-0.9.2.tgz
uncompress into /home/#####/data/lib/xhprof-0.9.2
cd ./xhprof-0.9.2/extension/
phpize
./configure 
make
make install
make test
mkdir /var/tmp/xhprof
```

The compiler seems to run fine. `make test` returns 8success, 0 failure.

then I'm adding the following to my php.ini (at /home/#####/etc):

```
[xhprof] extension=xhprof.so
xhprof.output_dir="/var/tmp/xhprof"
```

Note that I don't have access to the global php.ini file.

At this point, xhprof still doesn't work (ie - a call to xhprof_enable() returns a fatal error - undefined function)

Other specs:
PHP Version 5.2.14
Apache/2.0.54
My questiosn:
What is the proper php-config path?
How do I tell php to parse my additional php.ini file?

Am I doing anything else wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help..

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice guide on [mediatemple wiki](http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/%28gs%29:Install_xhprof) for setting up xhprof

Mediatemple has a hosting specific php.ini which you can use to setup.

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same problem. But at last I solve it. This is because the Xhprof is not accurately loaded. If you run `php -m` which is used to show the extensions of PHP, you will find there is no Xhprof.

The steps which you install the xhprof is right, but maybe you chose a wrong `php.ini` file.

Maybe there are two files named php.ini, the one's location is `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` , and another's location is `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`'. At first, some people may don't know where the php.ini is, so he write a file just named 'phpinfo.php' include a function 'phpinfo()' to find the location, and he enter the `http://localhost/phpinfo.php` at the broswer ,then glance over the page and find the 'Loaded Configuration File' is '/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini' ,so he add the [xhprof] into it.

But  **the '/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini' is for apache, and the '/etc/php5/cli/php.ini' is for client. So we should add the  following to '/etc/php5/cli/php.ini' and just restart the apache.**

Comment: Hi, nodejh and welcome to Server Fault. Apparently, you've undid my edits. The edits was mean to improve your post like: fix some typos and highlighting some important strings. See [Why can people edit my posts?](http://serverfault.com/help/editing)

Comment: Hi,thank you for fixing typos for me! And I try to message you for thanks, but i dont no how to operate it -.-

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.

I am using PHP5.6 so i could easily install XhProf using the following:

apt-get install php5.6-xhprof

Try something similar to your version of php.

Answer (score 0):

probably it wasnt loaded. Check using "php -m"